# Make building for x86_64 but glfw installed from homebrew is for arm64 (aarch64)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, makefile, clang

My project was building fine with make, until I imported stb, now I get this error

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/lib/libglfw.3.4.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::initWindow() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwCreateWindowSurface", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::createSurface() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::cleanup() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwGetFramebufferSize", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::chooseSwapExtent(VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR const&) in main.cpp.o
      HelloTriangleApplication::recreateSwapChain() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::getRequiredExtensions() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwGetWindowUserPointer", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::framebufferResizeCallback(GLFWwindow*, int, int) in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::initWindow() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwPollEvents", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::mainLoop() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::initWindow() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwSetWindowUserPointer", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::initWindow() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::cleanup() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWaitEvents", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::recreateSwapChain() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowHint", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::initWindow() in main.cpp.o
  "_glfwWindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      HelloTriangleApplication::mainLoop() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [vulkanLearning] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/vulkanLearning.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like the program is compiling for x86_64, but the libglfw I've installed from homebrew is for aarch64. How do I get it to compile for aarch64?

CMakelists.txt is using C++20, it's a Vulkan proj (Using custom env vars)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)
project(
    vulkanLearning VERSION 0.1.0
    DESCRIPTION "vulkanLearning"
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

# Specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
# Set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
# Set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 3.3 REQUIRED)

if (VULKAN_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found Vulkan, Including and Linking now")
    include_directories(${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${Vulkan_LIBRARIES} glfw)
endif (VULKAN_FOUND)
```

Comment: You seem to be compiling using make. Can you show the command used for compilation? (If you're using an IDE, you should be able to change to platform architecture in the settings)

Comment: Added CMakelists.txt to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if CMake is building for x86_64 even though your processor runs on arm64. This is influenced by `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`, so that should be `arm64`.

Setting the CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURE should override that default so that it will build your application for arm64:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64")
```

That will force clang (or whatever compiler you're using) to compile for arm64.

Comment: This fixes things perfectly, but the real problem was my stupidity in using an integrated terminal that was for some reason an x86_64 terminal. Thank you so much